# How would one simulate a post click with curl?

Tags: php, http, curl

So essentially I am trying to simulate a form post using php curl. I use something similar to below...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/update/93827');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Subject=test&Content=test');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now that's all fine however, the website I am using requires that every field be complete and by what I saw when I was doing it manually and looking on firebug... It looks a tad unreasonable to get all that data (As you can tell from above, I only need to do 2 fields, however the website requires about 17 different fields that aren't required if you do it manually).

I have always gotten away doing it with the above method, but I thought it might just be easier if there was a way to input your data into the fields and actually simulating a post click so the website does what it requires to do.

If you are confused by what I mean I can elaborate more.

Cheer

Comment: Perhaps the site you are scraping has tightened up on their incoming requests. Just set all the fields in curl using http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is 1 way to do it. It forces a 'refresh' to the url specified after 0 seconds (immediately)
This WILL NOT work if you want to post values to a page, but I note you are using a query string in the url anyway.

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ,URL=http://http://example.com/update/93827?Subject=test&Content=test">';
```

Comment: if you're calling from a php page, make sure you echo the above.